# Detect which app wants to open my app by URL scheme

Tags: swift, url-scheme

I want to detect which app opened my app by URL Schemes and check if I know that app I will pass data to.

When two apps signed with the same certificate I could detect the source app bundle identifier but otherwise I can't.

The code below just works for apps with the same developer team

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if let bundle = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, bundle == "secondapphamedd" {
            let uRLComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
            let query = uRLComponents?.queryItems
            let card = query![0].value
            return true
        } 
}
```

Is it possible with URL schemes? How?

Comment: You are saying `if let bundle = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, bundle == "secondapphamedd"` So if the source application is _not_ `"secondapphamedd"` the whole thing fails.

Comment: @matt when an app with another developer team want to open my app, bundle identifier is nil. It seem we can't detect bundle identifier of apps with different developer team, because of security issues.

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is I don't see how you know that from the code you showed. It never stops to test the bundle identifier for nil.

Comment: @matt I know, this is my sample code, In this code I check bundle identifier if there is. `options` is a dictionary, sometime it has two key/value sometimes it has one, when I open first app from second app if these apps signed with same certificate it has two key/value  `sourceApplication` is one of them. if they signed with different certificate,  `sourceApplication` is not there.